Marriage with the intention of divorce
What is the ruling on marrying a person with the intention of divorcing at a later unspecified date (not mutah). Would such a marriage contract be valid?

sunni
If the marriage is otherwise valid and the husband merely has the intention of giving divorce after some time then that is a valid marriage according to the Hanafis, Malikis, Shafi'is and one view of the Hanbalis. According to them intention does not count as a condition of the contract, as sometimes a person later decides to abstain from what he planned and sometimes he does what he did not initially plan to do.
It is considered makruh according to the Shafi'is in order to avoid the disagreement between the jurists.
It is invalid according to the second view of the Hanbalis and some other scholars as they consider it to be a form of Nikah al-Mutʿah.
Ref: Sharah Nawawi ,  Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah

Its not right. Nikkah is a sacred contract. Unless you do miysar marraige but even in miysar, divorce shouldnt be like a joke at all.

No problem. Assume a man divorces three times from his wife, then he no longer can return to his ex-wife until her wife is married to another man and divorce from him under certain conditions. So the marriage with that stranger man is in many situations with the intention of divorce at a later time at the very beginning.

`Abdullah ibn Masud (may Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) cursed the Muhallil and the Muhallal lahu. [The Muhallil is the one who marries a woman and divorces her so that she can go back to her first husband, and the Muhallal lahu is the first husband.] (Narrated and classed as authentic by At-Tirmidhi, 1120; also narrated by An-Nasa’i, 3416)  https://islamqa.info/en

@AhmbroDude, Divorce itself is discouraged in general but according to Islamic rules it is permissible, and the question is about rules.
